# Submiting Parent & Children in razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, submit, parent-child

Hi I am trying to submit parent and children, I am able to submit the Parent fine but not the children, is there any way to do this ?

this is my code.

```
@model IECWeb.Models.CurrencyDay

using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>CurrencyDay</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CurrencyDate)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CurrencyDate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CurrencyDate)
    </div>

    <p />

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Currency</th>
            <th>Rate</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Currency) {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => item.Name)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.Name)
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => item.Rate)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.Rate)
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

When I submit I get the CurrencyDay object But not the list of Currency

Thanks
sushiBite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend you using editor templates instead of writing loops in your views:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Currency</th>
        <th>Rate</th>
    </tr>
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Currency)
</table>
```

and then in the corresponding editor template which will be rendered for each element of the currency collection (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/CurrencyViewModel.cshtml`):

```
@model CurrencyViewModel
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Rate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Rate)
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Notice that the name and the location of the editor template is important. By convention the location should be either `~/Views/SomeController/EditorTemplates` (if the template is reused between actions of the controller) or more globally `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates`. The name of the editor template should be the name of the type of each element of the collection you are iterating over.

Comment: Thanks, this works better and I do not need to convert the ICollection to list and looks cleaner :D I will need to rewrite some of my code after seeing this :D thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Please read Phil Haacks article about Model Binding to a List.

[Model Binding To A List](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx)

**hope this helps**

Comment: thanks this works, but the answer from Darin was more in the direction I was looking for.