# Razor partial view prefix field names

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, partial-views

When using Razor to render a form for a complex Model that has sub-models, we'd usually use Partial Views to render the sub-models.

Simple example Model:

```
public class BlogPost
{
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

BlogPost.cshtml:

```
@model BlogPost

@Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Content)

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Comments.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.Partial('Comment', Model.Comments[i])
}
```

Comment.cshtml:

```
@model Comment

@Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Content)
```

**Now for the issue:**

Say we want to send the values of all fields to a controller action that takes `BlogPost` as a parameter. The fields are going to be posted back to the controller like so:

Content=The+content+of+the+BlogPost&Content=The+first+Comment&Content=The+second+Comment

But what we need to have MVC map them correctly to the `BlogPost` view model, we need this naming convention:

Content=The+content+of+the+BlogPost&Comments[0].Content=The+first+Comment&Comments[1].Content=The+second+Comment

How can this be achieved in a clean way? We can only think of two ways which both seem to compromise the design:

- Either we pass the `BlogPost` as a model to the partial view such that we can define the text area like so: `@Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Comments[i].Content)`. But this means we couple the partial view for comments to the parent view model - you could think of a scenario where the same partial view should be used in a different context, which is not possible if the partial view depends on the parent view model. Futhermore, the `i` would have to be passed to the partial view somehow.
- Or we fall back to explicitely defining the name of every single field with strings: `@Html.TextArea(ViewBag.Prefix + ".Content")`.

Is there any way to tell the partial view to apply a certain prefix to *all* field names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

chiccodoro,

if you create and EditorFor template of type `Comment`, mvc will handle all of this beautifully for you. However, that will only work well in a scenario where the rows are already present in the DB. Exampel from SO:

[Submiting Parent & Children in razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416712/submiting-parent-children-in-razor)

If you need to create new rows on the fly, then you'll have to use a little bit of trickery to allow the fields to operate as required. I used an article from steven sandersons website which allows you to add collection items at runtime and still retains unobtrusive validation etc. see this SO question and related article ref:

[Editing a Variable Length List, ASP.NET MVC 3 Style with Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153405/editing-a-variable-length-list-asp-net-mvc-3-style-with-table)

Comment: Thanks, EditorFor was the key! Also happy to read some Steven-Sanderson-Tips on how to handle new rows.

Comment: chiccodoro - glad that resolved your quandarry. the steven sanderson stuff has literally saved my bacon more times than i cvan say.